# Ctrl+Shift+X conflicts with Ctrl+X action

Tags: vb.net

We kept a menu item short cut key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) to pop up another form in Windows VB application. But when user tried to cut using (Ctrl+X) text from any field the above short cut action is firing and popping up another form.

No sure anything we missed or we should not use (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) as shortcut.

```
Me.mnuTools.Shortcut = System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut.CtrlShiftX
```

worst case we can change short cut but we wish to know is it something wrong using the short cut.

Please provide your views.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: If you want us to provide suggestions or give you our input we'll need to see your code, otherwise this'll just turn into a wild guessing game with a small chance of getting an actual answer.

Comment: code added, it is a single line of short cut key assignment in form initialization.

Comment: What is `mnuTools`? An item for a `MenuStrip`?

Comment: it is type of System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your problem please tell me what happens/don't happen and/or what you need help with and I'll try to assist you.

Comment: Apologies for delayed response. Actually we have two menu shortcuts for  cut(ctrl+X) and tools(ctrl+Shift+X). For cut action we are sending key stroke("^X") in the click event and for tools item click event just opening a new form. Here windows is not able to differentiate Ctrl+X from Ctrl+Shift+X. Initially i though it is issue with our application code, then i have created fresh sample application and issue occurs here as well. So it must be an issue with windows behavior. As i said in question we went with worst case, i.e. we changed the shortcut key. Thank you very much for your concern

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why it thinks <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> should call a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> hotkey, but I do believe I have a workaround.

When a cut action is performed Windows sends a [**`WM_CUT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649023(v=vs.85).aspx) message to the focused control. If we override [**`ProcessCmdKey()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) we can stop the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> combination from reaching any child controls of the form and instead send the `WM_CUT` message ourselves.

Untested, but I believe it should work:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr)
End Function

Private Const WM_CUT As Integer = &H300

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey (ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = (Keys.ControlKey Or Keys.X) AndAlso _
         Me.ActiveControl IsNot Nothing Then
        SendMessage(Me.ActiveControl.Handle, WM_CUT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) 'Send the WM_CUT message to the currently focused control.
        Return True 'Indicate that we've handled the message and stop the key strokes from reaching any child controls.
    End If
End Function
```

---

**EDIT:**

Future readers: I am aware that you can define the hotkeys on your own and call the respective methods in `KeyDown` or `ProcessCmdKey`, but I used the method above so that the menu item still can display its <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> hint.